# 'SysUtcDateTime' error during nopCommerce install - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nopcommerce

Having bought a copy of the shop made in nopCommerce (files and database) we are trying to implement it on our server. After copy, such mistake appears:

> **SysUtcDateTime' is not a recognized built-in function name.**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'SysUtcDateTime' is not a recognized built-in function name.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I found out [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/6441/sql2005-sysutcdatetime-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name.aspx#82244) that it might be connected with the wrong version of SQL server in Nop.BusinessLogic. So, after simple edit in Notepad++ I changed '2008' to '2005', but no effects : (

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running SQL 2005? There's a post on their forums that deals with this error: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/6441/sql2005-sysutcdatetime-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name.aspx

Comment: Never mind - just saw your link to the same post!

Comment: Yes, I am running now 2005, unfortunately (before it was 2008).
I changed the file as they said to, no results, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway...I know that the topic of nopcommerce is not that popular, but maybe someone will look here for similiar solution.

**I've got bad news** - it turned out that the server I was trying to use had some old and outdated services. Only tip I can give:

> Check the requirements of nopcommerce [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/technologysystemrequirements.aspx), make sure that the
>   .NET Framework is consistent with your current source code, as well as
>   the version of the database).

Or change the server provider that supports nopcommerce solutions - as I did and solved the problem.